# Chinese characters get unreadable when exported to excel in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{        
    static List<User> GetUsers()
    {
        List<User> list = new List<User>() { 
        new User{Id=1,Name="张三"},
        new User{Id=2,Name="lisi"},
        new User{Id=3,Name="wangwu"}
        };
        return list;
    }
    public void SaveToExcel()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("id").Append("\t");
        sb.Append("name").Append("\n");
        List<User> list = GetUsers();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            sb.Append(item.Id).Append("\t");
            sb.Append(item.Name).Append("\n");
        }
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
        Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=card.xls");
        Response.Write(sb.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
```

Chinese characters are displayed as "????" in excel.

Comment: Have you checked that the problem isn't when you call sb.ToString()? I understand that .NET strings are in Unicode (UTF-16) encoding format, so maybe that is causing your issue.

Comment: read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs0350fy(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` or a third party library like `Open XML` to write excel, more information can be found here:

[How to Create Excel file in ASP.NET C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/jayendra/how-to-create-excel-file-in-Asp-Net-C-Sharp/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Default;
Your default charset should be UTF-8